Enforcing Order in a Linear Programming Question
I have an optimization model to fulfill the water requirements of a city's distribution network. The model includes water sources from rainfall collection, river extraction, reservoir storage, and external supply. I need the model to prioritize the order of water sources to meet the demand: first from rainfall collection, then from river extraction, then from reservoir storage, and finally from external supply.
We have modelled it as such:
I am trying to solve a problem in which I have 4 variables: x1 (rainfall collection), x2 (river extraction), x3_t (reservoir storage drained), and x4_t (external supply). x_1 and x_2 can only be chosen once across all timestamps.
I need
x1+ x2 + x3_t + x4_t >= c_t, where t is the current timestamp
We also have x3_t < 100
I basically want to encode:
if x1 + x2 + x3_t >= c_t:
    x4_t = 0

How can I enforce that I drain the reservoir storage as much as possible, and only once its drained, do I use the external supply if there's any remaining demand?
We tried an attempt at big M, but we were quite confused how to make it work for this problem.

Since this is a theoretical modelling question, delete this question and move to the Operations Research site. Or if you have code, edit your question here to show the code.

You could write this:
if x1 + x2 + x3_t >= c_t:
    x4_t = 0

In the following way using big M formulation:
Constraint 1: x1 + x2 + x3_t + z * M >= c_t
Constraint 2: x4_t <= z * M
Where z is a binary variable to which you assign artificial cost in the objective function to ensure that if x1 + x2 + x3_t >= c_t z takes value of 0 an therefore x4_t <= 0. Take care to select value of big M large enough so that it does not provide an upper limit on x4_t, but also not excessively high so to cause numerical problems in the solver
